I'm trying to save my data in flutter with sqflite package but it is not working
the code below is my riverpod provider file which I am using sqflite and path package in there:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sql;
import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/models/coffee.dart';

Future<Database> _getDatabase() async {
  final dbPath = await sql.getDatabasesPath();
  final db = await sql.openDatabase(
    path.join(dbPath, 'coffee.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute(
          'CREATE TABLE cart_provider(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, coffeeImage TEXT, CoffeeName TEXT, CoffeePrice REAL)');
    },
    version: 1,
  );
  return db;
}

class CartNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Coffee>> {
  CartNotifier() : super([]);

  Future<void> loadCoffee() async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    final data = await db.query('cart_provider');
    final coffees = data
        .map(
          (row) => Coffee(
            id: row['id'] as String,
            coffeeImage: row['coffeeImage'] as String,
            coffeeName: row['coffeeName'] as String,
            coffeePrice: row['coffeePrice'] as double,
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    state = coffees;
  }

  void addCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    if (state.contains(coffee)) {
      return;
    } else {
      final db = await _getDatabase();
      db.insert(
        'cart_provider',
        {
          'id': coffee.id,
          'coffeeImage': coffee.coffeeImage,
          'coffeeName': coffee.coffeeName,
          'coffeePrice': coffee.coffeePrice,
        },
      );

      state = [...state, coffee];
    }
  }

  void removeCoffee(Coffee coffee) async {
    final db = await _getDatabase();
    await db.delete(
      'cart_provider',
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [coffee.id],
    );

    state = state.where((c) => c != coffee).toList();
  }
}

final cartProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CartNotifier, List<Coffee>>(
  (ref) {
    return CartNotifier();
  },
);

and the code below is where I am using the provider to show listView:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

import 'package:coffee_shop_app/provider/cart_provider.dart';
import 'package:coffee_shop_app/components/registered_coffee_item.dart';

class CartScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CartScreen> createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends ConsumerState<CartScreen> {
  late Future<void> _coffeesFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _coffeesFuture = ref.read(cartProvider.notifier).loadCoffee();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final registeredCoffees = ref.watch(cartProvider);

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _coffeesFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) =>
          snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
              ? const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Column(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 20,
                          vertical: 20,
                        ),
                        child: ListView(
                          children: [
                            ...registeredCoffees.map((coffee) {
                              return RegisteredCoffeeItem(
                                coffee: coffee,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                              );
                            }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
    );
  }
}

the problem is that when I reload my app the data is not saved!
I checked my codes a few times and I watched some youtube videos. everything looks fine even in my debug console but when I reload my app the data is not saved.

try Calling the loadCoffee within the constructor of CartNotifier so every time there is a change in the state which in your case is List<Coffee> the loadCoffee gets called. try this:
class CartNotifier extends StateNotifier<List<Coffee>> {
  CartNotifier() : super([]) {
    // Load the coffee data when the notifier is initialized
    loadCoffee();
  }
...

and also in this way there is no need of ConsumerStatefulWidget in your CartScreen, it should be like this:
class CartScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CartScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final registeredCoffees = ref.watch(cartProvider);

    return registeredCoffees.isEmpty
        ? const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                    vertical: 20,
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                    children: [
                      ...registeredCoffees.map((coffee) {
                        return RegisteredCoffeeItem(
                          coffee: coffee,
                          icon: Icons.delete,
                        );
                      }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
  }
}


Thanks for your advice, I am trying your solution but again is not working , when I restart the app my provider again is empty. is not related to internet or other issues ?

don't mention it @EhsanJavdan. your app appears to be using SQLite for local data storage, which I guess should not be affected by internet accessibility limitations. As long as the database is set up correctly and the app has permissions to access local storage, it should be able to save and retrieve data locally. and your code looks clean to me. Try adding some debug prints to your methods to see if data is fetched successfully or not
